# Scrapy Doesn't output json when called from another script

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I've written a scrapy crawler to fetch me some sweet sweet data and it works. I'm very impressed with myself for the achievement. I even created a jupyter notebook to process the data from the Json file I created.

But I've creatyed the program so that people at work can use it and getting them to navigate to a folder and use command lines isn't going to work so I wanted to make something that I can call on and then process afterwards. But for some reason Scrapy just isnt playing ball. I've found a few bits of help but once the crawl has been completed the json output I've requested doesn't appear. But when i command line it, it shows up.

```
def parse(self, response):
        resp_dict = json.loads(response.body)
        f = open(file_name, 'w')
        json.dump(resp_dict, f, indent=4)
        f.close()
```

this is the bit that works, sometimes. I just don't understand why it wont give me an output when called from a different script.  I've also tried to add this in but I think i'm putting it in the wrong place.

```
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'json')
settings.set('FEED_URI', 'result.json')
```

I can successfully call the Scrapy Spider, i can see the terminal showing me what's going on. But I just can't get the json output. Literally tearing my hair out now.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    }
})

process.crawl(HoggleSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: What does your separate script look like?

Comment: It's the bottom piece of code in the question. There's other bits in it but it's centred around creating dataframes from the json output. Both scripts work independently just not together.

Comment: I think your going about it in the total wrong way.  saving the information to a file from inside the parse method is kind of antithetical to the scrapy workflow.  How do you expect the it to export anything to the Feeds file when you don't yield any results?

Comment: It does work though. When i do scrapy crawl hoggle from the command line i get the expected output. When i call process.start() from another script i can see the program working. It just doesnt save the output.

Comment: So if i call process.start() and change the scrapy parse method to yield json.dump(resp_dict, f, indent=4) would that work?